# "What","when" and "that" - are they conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions

> It was no strain on the voice, and I guessed **that** Miss Glaser knew
>   **what** she was doing **when** she chose it.

What parts of speech are "what", "when" and "that"?

I assume they are subordinating conjunctions but they may  be pronouns or adverbs.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples according to modern grammar the word *that* is a subordinator; the word *what* is a pronoun; the word *when* is a preposition.

In old fashioned grammar the word *that* is a subordinating conjunction, *what* is a pronoun and *when* is a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Could you, please, as well tell me what type of pronoun is **"what"**. Probably a **relative** one?

Comment: @Daisy Yes, we'd call it a relative pronoun :) In your example, that is. There's also an interrogative pronoun too!

Comment: Interrogative pronoun? I thought we use them only in questions...what do you mean?

Comment: @Daisy No! not in your example! I just meant that there is more that  one pronoun called "what"! :-) So the word "what" isn't *always* a relative pronoun, that's all.